# replacing show() with showdialog()

Tags: c#, showdialog

I am opening a form at run time from the main gui form using `form.showdialog();`

I set the proppeties likeform should appear in center etc

```
 form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

and added a label

```
Label popupLabel1 = new Label();
form.Controls.Add(popupLabel1);
```

**Problem is** when i replace form.showdialog() with form.show() I cant see the content of label and now this new form does not appear in the center. Why these set properties are not occuring ?

Thanls

Comment: change `form.Show()` to `form.Show(this)` for this `form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;` to work as for the label problem, from this part of code there is no way to say what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't showing your full code, which is necessary in the case. When and where is what code executed?

What you need to remember is that .Show() is not a blocking call, while .ShowDialog() is a blocking call. This means that if you have code *after* the .Show/ShowDialog call, this won't be executed immediately when you use ShowDialog - it will be executed when the form is closed.

Assuming you have code like this:

```
var form = new YourForm();
form.Show(); // NOT BLOCKING!
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
Label popupLabel1 = new Label();
form.Controls.Add(popupLabel1);
```

If you change the Show to ShowDialog, then you need to move it to the end, after the creation of the labels.

```
var form = new YourForm();
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
Label popupLabel1 = new Label();
form.Controls.Add(popupLabel1);
form.ShowDialog(); // BLOCKING!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying a form using Show() and not ShowDialog(), you need to set its MDI parent child properties.

try following code:

```
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
form.MdiParent = this;
form.Show();
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention MDI at all.